# AppleScript find the user's set default browser?

Tags: macos, applescript, web-browser

I've been doing some research on this topic but it seems Apple has changed their file hierarchy. From the MacScripter post "[Get user default browser](https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=27553)" it references the line:

```
 set pListpath to (path to preferences as Unicode text) & "com.apple.LaunchServices.plist"
```

but when running the handler in Sierra I'm returned an error that the file is empty.  Further research I found "[How to use an AppleScript app bundle as the default browser in os x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554093/how-to-use-an-applescript-app-bundle-as-the-default-browser-in-os-x)" and "[Use default browser in custom Apple Script?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2031330)" that suggest:

```
on open location theURL
 ...
end open location
```

but I'm wanting to preserve the browser in a variable to reference later on in my script.  In Sierra is there a file or way to reference what the default browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, the file for has changed to `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist`.

I'm running macOS 10.13 (High Sierra), but the script *should* work with Sierra as well. Please report back.

```
# return default browser in macOS
# https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313454/applescript-find-the-users-set-default-browser
# tested with macOS 10.13.3

set default_browser to do shell script "x=~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist; \\
plutil -convert xml1 $x; \\
grep 'https' -b3 $x | awk 'NR==2 {split($2, arr, \"[><]\"); print arr[3]}'; \\
plutil -convert binary1 $x"

if default_browser is "org.mozilla.firefox" then
    set browser_name to "Firefox"
else if default_browser is "com.apple.safari" then
    set browser_name to "Safari"
else
    set browser_name to "Probably Google Chrome"
end if
```

The output will look like this:

> com.apple.safari
>
> org.mozilla.firefox

Comment: that works.  Doesn't give the exact output I'd hope for but I can write a conditional further to define the application.  Would prefer an all AppleScript solution but I know sometimes a `do shell script` is needed.

Comment: I've realized with Apple it's sometimes better to code it as `if default_browser contains "firefox" then`.  Food for thought but both approaches work.

Comment: this is horrible! the file in `$x` is converted to xml and then back to binary. better use `plutil -convert xml1 -o - "$x"` to convert to stdout, and pipe that to grep ....

Answer (score 5):

For **OS X 10.10** and later, use the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
set defaultBrowser to do shell script "defaults read \\
    ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure \\
    | awk -F'\"' '/http;/{print window[(NR)-1]}{window[NR]=$2}'"

if defaultBrowser is "" or defaultBrowser contains "safari" then
    --  # The default Browser is Safari.
    set defaultBrowser to "Safari"
    --  # Your code goes here.
else if defaultBrowser contains "chrome" then
    --  # The default Browser is Google Chrome.
    set defaultBrowser to "Google Chrome"
    --  # Your code goes here.
else if defaultBrowser contains "firefox" then
    --  # The default Browser is Firefox.
    set defaultBrowser to "Firefox"
    --  # Your code goes here.
else
    set defaultBrowser to "Other"
    --  # Your code goes here.
end if
```

**Note:** The start of the `if defaultBrowser` *statement* tests for nothing `""` as well as `"safari"`, because, if **Safari** is the only *Browser* installed or if another *Browser* is installed and has never had a default *Browser* set, then by default nothing will be returned by the `do shell script "defaults ..."` *command*, and this means **Safari** is the default *Browser*.

In the *example* **AppleScript** *code* above, the *value* of the `defaultBrowser` *variable* initially gets set to one of the following *values*:

- Nothing: `""`
- `com.apple.safari`
- `com.google.chrome`
- `org.mozilla.firefox`
- Some other: `output`

Then within the `if` *statement*, the `defaultBrowser` gets set to the proper name of the *Browser*. Although you can certainly modify as needed/wanted.

Also note that the `do shell script` *command* used herein is more efficient then the other answer, which needlessly uses the `plutil` *command* to first convert the *binary plist* file to an *xml plist* file and then back to a *binary plist* file afterwards. It also needlessly uses both `grep` and `awk` when both are not necessary since `defaults` and `awk` (or just `defaults` and `grep`) can do it without all the extra rigmarole.

---

For pre **OS X 10.10, replace:**

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure
```

With:

```
com.apple.LaunchServices
```

In the `do shell script "defaults ..."` *command*.

Comment: Important to remember there's also an entry for https in addition to http.